# Access is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, hard-drive, ntfs

I'm trying to mount a drive with:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 usb
```

I get this error:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

I use:

```
fuser -m /dev/sda1
```

and get back a huge list:

```
/dev/sda1:               1rce     2rce     3rce     5rce     7rce     8rce     9rce    10rce    11rce    12rce    13rce    15rce    16rce    17rce    18rce    20rce    21rce    22rce    23rce    25rce    26rce    27rce    28rce    29rce    30rce    31rce    32rce    33rce    34rce    35rce    36rce    37rce    38rce    39rce    43rce    44rce    45rce    46rce    62rce    63rce    67rce    68rce    69rce    70rce    71rce    72rce    73rce    74rce    75rce    76rce    77rce    78rce    79rce    80rce    81rce    82rce    83rce    84rce    85rce    86rce    87rce    88rce    89rce    90rce    95rce   108rce   109rce   151rce   152rce   157rce   158rce   159rce   160rce   161rce   162rce   163rce   164rce   165rce   166rce   167rce   168rce   175rce   177rce   262rce   264rce   265rce   294rce   307rce   425rce   527rce   566rce   567rce   598rce   683rce   724rce   725rce   726rce   727rce   728rce   810rce   819rce   824rce   827rce   830rce   832rce   836rce   837rce   850rce   863rce   868rce   893rce   897rce   909rce   911rce   944rce   949rce   962rce   979rce   996rce  1026rce  1029rce  1037rce  1038rce  1039rce  1040rce  1041rce  1042rce  1102rce  1229rce  1268rce  1285rce  1323rce  1395rce  1405rce  1413rce  1419rce  1428re  1507rce  1515rce  1527re  1554re  1559rce  1564rce  1585rce  1596rce  1598rce  1602re  1604re  1605re  1607re  1620re  1647rce  1649re  1654re  1656re  1660re  1664re  1665re  1672re  1675re  1680re  1700rce  1703re  1712rce  1728re  1729re  1730re  1736re  1739re  1741re  1742re  1743re  1747re  1798re  1807rce  1809rce  1814re  1856re  1862re  1863re  1877rce  1889rce  1901rce  1907rce  1912rce  1920rce  1928rce  1938rce  1949rce  2067rce  2077rce  2079rce  2097rce  2141rce  2148re  2157re  2164rce  2168rce  2175rce  2200rce  2202rce  2211rce  2314re  2316re  2337rce  2458re  2635re  2671rce  3023re  3041re  3696rce  4095rce  4370rce  4422rce  4782rce  4800rce  4915rce  4922rce  5012rce  5015rce  5053re  5060rce  7686rce  7809rce 13428rce 14203rce 14204rce 14208rce 14283rce 28222rce 28282rce 28284rce 28285rce 28370rce 28372rce 28373rce 28382rce 28383rce 28385rce 28511rce 28521rce 28550rce 28578rce 28591rce 28593rce 28595rce 28633rce 28857rce 28897rce 28910rce 28972rce 28997rce 29092rce 29152rce 29153rce 29226rce
```

Not sure what's happening. How can I kill all the other connections and mount this drive?

(I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411392/undelete-access-is-denied-because-the-ntfs-volume-is-already-exclusively-opened) similar question but I found it unclear and I'm not trying to undelete anything, I'm just trying to mount this drive which worked perfectly fine before I wiped my laptop when upgrading from Ubuntu 14 to 16. As soon as I was on a new system I started having a problem. Though I've tried and failed with a bunch of solutions from online so it could be that I created all these processes at some point I'm not sure. Either way I thought it was worth opening a new question.)

*Update:* the command `mount` responds with:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1943712k,nr_inodes=485928,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=392632k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd,nsroot=/)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,nsroot=/)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer,nsroot=/)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=392632k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/home/.ecryptfs/heim/.Private on /home/heim type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=8b5e55b44798c614,ecryptfs_sig=bff979ff1961fd73,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to mount a drive with:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 usb
> ```

That is **not** the drive you think it is. Look:

> *Update:* the command `mount` responds with:
>
> ```
> [...]
> /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
> [...]
> ```

`/dev/sda1` is already mounted and it is **your root drive** which contains the main file system of your Ubuntu installation. It is not a NTFS partition of an external USB drive (I assume you want to mount a USB drive because you created a mount point called `usb`).

You shall check the partition tables of all drives with:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you are using GPT for any of the drives, you might need to run:

```
sudo parted -l
```

*Probably* the partition you want to access is `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: in my case it was already mounted (automatically). By `mount` command I could see it already mounted in a directory. (ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). (limace255's answer case)

Answer (score 9):

it means in general that your device has been already mounted (automatically, for example, when detected).Depending on what displays 'mount' command, you can 'umount' your device, and then try to remount it as you want.

Comment: looks like ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS mounts it automatically. thanks!